# How to Display only visible images through Selenium scripts

Tags: selenium

Right now my application is displaying only 12 images in the front end, but while fetching through xpath it is showing 18 images.

Used x-path as:

```
driver.findElemnt(By.xpath("xpath")).size();
```

Used code:

```
int showCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoImage_XPATH"))).size();

for (int i = 1; i <= showCount; i++) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoImage_XPATH"))).isDisplayed();
                        i=i+1;
                        log.info(i + "shows are present in GET TO KNOW THE SHOW section (Count of only shows which are displaying on screen).\n");
}
```

I need to display only 12 images.

Comment: Add the actual xpath and the page source to your question...

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to validate here? If you are looking to validate the active images (in your question I believe it is 12), use the dynamic xpath/css with attribute related to active images. It would be easy for us if you can share the HTML code.

Comment: Hi, All are active images but based on resolution screen images displaying

Answer (score 0):

You could run a javascript to verify that all the images are loaded properly, find the small piece of code below to do it.

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver (driver);

List<WebElement> allImages = eventFiringWebDriver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
int countBrokenImages = 0;
List<String> brokenimageUrl = new ArrayList<String>();

String script = "return (typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth!=\"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth>0)";

for (WebElement image : allImages) 
{   
    Object imgStatus = eventFiringWebDriver.executeScript(script, image);          
    if(imgStatus.equals(false))
    {
        String  currentImageUrl = image.getAttribute("src");
        String imageUrl = currentImageUrl ;
        brokenimageUrl.add(imageUrl);
        countBrokenImages++;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.